# Automated data processing in BPMN/BPEL?

Tags: data, domain-model, diagrams, bpm, bpmn

In order to run complex simulations, I need to do preprocessing of data from various data sources. This is done by a bunch of Postgresql scripts. However, having only these is unsatisfactory, because they are not very intelligible, maintainable etc. I want to express the data preprocessing using BPMN/BPEL, which would allow me to graphically visualise

- the different data sources and sinks
- the flow of data between them
- filtering of data according to some conditions
- merging of data
- transformations on the data (which are usually simple computations)

Is there a possibility of attaching Postgresql snippets to my BPMN or BPEL model, such that I just can run the BPMN/BPEL in order to execute the data processing?

Comment: what language / technology to take up next is explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic]. See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6486/40980

Comment: OK, have reformulated my question such that hopefully now it is in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with BPMN tool that are available today as they usually provides layer to connect to external system or database. By example, Bonita BPM has a feature called "connector" to integrate third-party systems.

As far as the BPEL that I'm not sure as this language is mainly designed to orchestrate web-services, so unless you have an web-services layer to interface your PostGreSQL DB, I don't think it would be a good option.

Another option you should consider is using an ETL tool (Extract, Transform, Load). It's a concept (not a standard, as BPMN is) that usually uses for data integration between heterogeneous systems.